# In Log4j2, Is it possible to filter out certain key value pairs from the logger based on the key?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

Can Log4j2 be configured in such a way that the filters or some other components can filter out certain values from getting printed in the log? (but should allow other fields in the same line to pass through)

Say the following lines appear in the log

```
 [operation=DONE, userName=junitUser, tenant=Tenant [tenantID=default], needDetails=1, message=BaseMsg [version=1.0, sdk=AppSDK [version=1.3, protocols=[4aac81ca, 393ae7a0]], device=Device [id=12345, type=Pompom, info=Dot's Device]]], channel=null
 [operation=DONE, userName=junitUser224, tenant=Tenant [tenantID=default], needDetails=1, message=BaseMsg [version=1.0, sdk=AppSDK [version=1.3, protocols=[4aac81ca,393ae7a0]], device=Device [id=123456, type=Mamamia, info=tom's Device]]], channel=null
```

Now can I filter out the "userName" field in such a way that the log lines now do not contain it as shown below?

```
 [operation=DONE, tenant=Tenant [tenantID=default], needDetails=1, message=BaseMsg [version=1.0, sdk=AppSDK [version=1.3, protocols=[4aac81ca, 393ae7a0]], device=Device [id=12345, type=Pompom, info=Dot's Device]]], channel=null
 [operation=DONE, tenant=Tenant [tenantID=default], needDetails=1, message=BaseMsg [version=1.0, sdk=AppSDK [version=1.3, protocols=[4aac81ca,393ae7a0]], device=Device [id=123456, type=Mamamia, info=tom's Device]]], channel=null
```

Here is my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="/Users/dunston/logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
        <RegexFilter regex=".* zinger_log .*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>

      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>         
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, without rolling your own extensions. However, it looks like your logging a data structure, yes? If so, why not write a method that you'd call instead, which removes the username from the data structure before logging it?

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for the response. One thing that I was looking to achieve was ease of 'configurability'. Like I could allow an end user to allow/disallow certain fields by changing the log4j2 configuration, if such a facility was already available as a part of the package. I also started filtering a copy of the datastructure specifically for generating this type of a log. Probably get the field names via ThreadContext in log4j2 and filter the fields' key and value out before writing it to a rolling file log. Not sure if other elegant approaches are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a [RewriteAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RewriteAppender).

You may need to write a custom [RewritePolicy](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rewrite/RewritePolicy.java) that inspects the LogEvent's Message and replaces the Message with another instance if the formatted message contains a regular expression that you want to filter out.

Your custom RewitePolicy can be configured in the configuration like any other standard Log4j2 [plugin](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! Will check it out and update the thread.

Comment: It appears to work. On a similar note, for cases where I have a string csv like pattern to log instead of a map, I think I may have to fall back on regex replace using PatternLayout approach?